# get text from jtextarea split it and pass it to jlabel on new line?

Tags: java, user-interface

hi friends im new here i write a code in two classes where in one class i declare a jtextarea and a  button when we click the button then text will split and it display in the jlabel but here is problem is that the text is written in jtext area and button also working but when jlabel frame open it show nothing here is my code
 the first class

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Try extends JFrame {

    JTextArea text;
    String string;
   public Try(){

 super("survey");
          Container container=getContentPane();
          container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          text=new JTextArea();
                text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,150));
           string=text.getText();
         JButton showDialogBtn = new JButton("Add Text");
        container.add(text);
        container.add( showDialogBtn);

       showDialogBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     jlabel l=new jlabel();
     l.setSize(700,700);
   l.setVisible(true);          
            }
      });


   }  





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Try t=new Try();
        t.setSize(400,500);
  t.setVisible(true);
    }

    String getArray()
  {
  return  string ;
           }

}
```

But the second class that is jlabel class is not showing the required result plz help in this regard

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;
 class jlabel extends JFrame {
 Try t=new Try();
   public jlabel(){
          JFrame frame=new JFrame("jlabel");
          JPanel jp1=new JPanel();
   String string=t.getArray();
    String[] labelStrings = string.split(" \\s*");   
     for (String labelString : labelStrings)
    {
      // create JLabels and add
      JLabel label = new JLabel(labelString);
      jp1.add(label);
      frame.add(jp1);

    }



 }
 }
```

waiting for reply thanks in advance
Regards,

Comment: i couldn't understand you. can you clarify your question? (what the code should do?)

Comment: yes a little bit and im working on it

Answer (score 1):

The first class is decent, but the "jLabel" class had so many bugs. Please see below the one that works.

A summary of the issues in the jlabel class:

- Another Try object was instantiated and this instance was used
- You were creating a new JFrame even though you were subclassing it already.
- No layout manager.

And so on...

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Label extends JFrame {

    public Label(String string) {
        super("jlabel");
        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        String[] labelStrings = string.split(" \\s*");
        for (String labelString : labelStrings) {
            // create JLabels and add
            JLabel label = new JLabel(labelString);
            jp1.add(label);
        }
        getContentPane().add(jp1);
    }
}
```

In the Try class, initialize it this way:

```
Label l = new Label(text.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the getText() outside the actionPerformed() method. This method is run when the button is pressed, so if you want to get text then, you should call the method getText() within actionPerformed().

Your code gets text as soon as it is run and all it can find is nothing! So, that's what is pastes into the JLabel.

Comment: yes i did but not get the required result now i modify my code